# Extract words from Excel cell with limitation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I'm trying to extract some text from Excel, there are thousands data, so I think it would be cool if there's a fast way to do things. Anyway, here's how it goes:

Cell A1 has: (RI-650;RJ-7500;KM-1000;TL-650;) <--4 variables (RI-650, RJ-7500, KM-1000, and TL-650)

While cell A2 has: (RI-650;RJ-11875;KM-1000;RB-5000;TL-650;) <--5 variables, plus RB-5000 from above example.

Can I get in B1, C1, D1, E1, and so on filled with each variable? Example in B columns I get RI-xxx and C columns I get RJ-xxx, and so on? I've tried LEFT, RIGHT, MID, and some IFs, but got stuck.

Any insight on this one?

Comment: Take a look at the Text to Columns function in the Data tab.

Comment: @pnuts I'm trying to split the content

Comment: @AbieGiordano How many different variable columns will you have total?

Comment: @Chrismas007 5 variables in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are indeed brackets bookending the value use **Find & Replace** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to get rid of them.

When the opening and closing brackets are removed (if they actually were there), select all of column A and choose Data ► Data Tools ► Text to Columns. On the first screen of the wizard select Delimited and click <kbd>Next</kbd>. On the second screen of the wizard put a check beside Semicolon and clear everything else. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

If it was your intention to retain the values in column A, copy and paste them into column B and adjust the method above to split them out.

Comment: @pnuts - The *there are thousands data* tells me that this is the most viable solution. With a minimum of 2K rows and an unknown number of 'variables' to split off, T2C is ideal. If it was a repetitious task, a quick VBA Sub would make short work of it and not leave behind non-blank empty strings in the ragged edge output.

Comment: @Jeeped works like magic, thanks! (fyi, it IS 2K columns, lol)

Answer (score 2):

This formula will do what you are looking for assuming your variables are separated by "`;`".  If they are seperated by another character or a space, then just replace the "`;`" with that character or space.  Don't forget to change the variable to search for with each new column you create.  Just copy this down the column for each variable:

**Edit: Updated Formula**  You can now copy this formula across assuming the variable names are in B1, C1, D1, etc given my example in my picture. (More universal formula)

```
=IF(FIND(B$1, $A2)>0, MID($A2, FIND(B$1, $A2), FIND(";", $A2, FIND(B$1,$A2))-FIND(B$1, $A2)), "Nothing")
```

[image: ScreenCap]

Comment: nice solution effort! if I could choose more than one answer in SO I would definitely choose this one!

Answer (score -1):

A solution is to use a the FIND function to parse your terms, and then use the MID function to generate the substrings

**Here's how :** 
*STEP 1:* With Cell A1 containing (RI-650;RJ-7500;KM-1000;TL-650;) 
you can calculate the break points with
Cell F1 to J1 as

> |    1       |  =FIND(";",$A1,F1+1)  |  =FIND(";",$A1,G1+1)  | 
>   =FIND(";",$A1,H1+1)   |  =FIND(";",$A1,I1+1)

*STEP 2:*  Set Cell B1 to E1 as

> |  =MID($A1,F1+1,G1-F1-1) |  =MID($A1,G1+1,H1-G1-1)   | 
>   =MID($A1,H1+1,I1-H1-1)    |  =MID($A1,I1+1,J1-I1-1)

NOTES :

1. The formulas can be written once and copied right.
2. You can hide the FIND values if you need to.

Comment: This doesn't solve his issue where he has different variables in each string and needs them in different columns depending on the variable.

Comment: Thx.  U R right ... I didn't read the question properly.  I thought it was just a simple parsing question.